# I cannot add views when reverse engineering my database in Visio

Tags: sql-server, view, reverse-engineering, visio

I am trying to reverse engineer parts of a 2012 SQL Server into Microsoft Visio 2010. The views option is greyed out. The views are integral to the processes I am trying to document, and the diagram will be useless without them. Does anyone have an easy work-around other than manually inputting the views?

Comment: Check the permissions on the account you're using to connect to the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably using "wrong" data provider to reverse engineer the database, and that is the reason why views are disabled. There are some issues with Visio not being updated to support newer SQL server versions. Try the following:

1. Start "reverse engineer" wizard
2. Select **Generic OleDb data provider** (not the "Microsoft SQL Sver"). Click Next.
3. The dialog pops up, select **SQL Native Client** there, then (on the "Connection" tab) your server, and your database. Click OK.
4. Now the "views" checkbox should be enabled.

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I had been selecting Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server.

Comment: Worked like a charm..Thanks!