# Reverse Engineer SQL Server 2012 to Visio 2010

Tags: sql-server, driver, reverse-engineering, visio

I've been trying to reverse engineer a database to a MS Visio diagram. At first I had to downgrade my 2013 version of Visio to 2010 because apparently they removed the feature.

And now I've tried what seems like every single driver out there. I managed to find ODBC drivers that work but then I can only import the tables and I don't get any information of the views, procedures etc.

I tried the following drivers:

- ODBC Driver 11 For SQL Server (2014.120.4219..)
- SQL Server (6.01.7601.17514)
- SQL Server Native Client 10.0 (2007.100.2531.00)
- SQL Server Native Client 11.0 (2011.110.5058.00)
- Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
- Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server

The server in question is running the following version:

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)

Awesome if anyone has any help here. Would save me tons of time :)

Comment: If you don't see tables and views it means you don't have the proper permissions. Retrieving an object's description for example is a *different* permission from SELECT

Comment: I tried different drivers, and all of them always say "connection succeeded" to the database. With all drivers I manage to retrieve only tables. The option for me to retrieve viewobjects from the database is always "greyed out". I'm guessing therefore I need a different driver.

Comment: No. It means that you can't retrieve the views. Or that VIsio 2010 has a problem.  If there *was* a problem with all drivers, people would have noticed. Can you see and edit the views from SSMS using the *same* credentials?

Comment: Yes. I am certain that these credentials have full rights to the database. I have over the past year developed tables, views, functions, procedures (all within the same schema) for a client. Now my idea was to generate a database model diagram using Visio on my personal computer by connection to the server and reverse engineering the database. I managed to get it to work, but for some reason only database tables.

I think the main problem is that these drivers don't correctly support never versions of SQL Server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573931/i-cannot-add-views-when-reverse-engineering-my-database-in-visio looks like Generic OLEDB worked as per the linked answer...